# How to get youtube download url from video id?

Tags: java, api, youtube

How does tools like IDM,savefrom.net etc grab youtube video download url from video id ?

What I done is:

1. get video `token` from `/get_video_info?video_id=ID` like:

   `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=8hYlB38asDY`
2. Download video by requesting it from `/get_video?video_id=ID&t=TOKEN&fmt=FORMAT_ID&asv=2` like:

   `http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=8hYlB38asDY&t=vjVQa1PpcFMgAK0HB1VRbinpVOwm29eGugPh3fBi6Dg%3D&fmt=18&asv=2`

   As said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311795/youtube-video-download-url).

but it's shows nothing.

I think the way I done is deprecated. I searched a lot in google but nothing found helpful.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong link. i wanted to post [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11057489/3102124) . Even this is JavaScript, i think you can use the idea behind that.

Comment: Look at the comment below the answer from @Bikush

Comment: The problem is, that Google or other video platforms  always changes their code. If you try to download from any webpages, which is not owned by you, then you have to stay uptodate, any time. I think there is sure some one who parsed the url from the page. But to relay on that for a long time is not a good idea.